# Lua - How do I use a function from another script?

Tags: function, lua, calculator

I've been looking around and I have not been able to find anything that has worked for me. I'm starting to learn more Lua and to start off I'm making a simple calculator. I was able to get each individual operation onto separate programs, but when I try to combine them I just can't get it to work. My script as it is now is

```
require "io"
require "operations.lua"

do
print ("Please enter the first number in your problem.")
x = io.read()
print ("Please enter the second number in your problem.")
y = io.read()
print ("Please choose the operation you wish to perform.")
print ("Use 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, and 4 for division.")
op = io.read()
op = 1 then
    function addition
op = 2 then
    function subtraction
op = 3 then
    function multiplication
op = 4 then
    function division
print (answer)
io.read()
end
```

and my operations.lua script is

```
function addition
    return answer = x+y
end

function subtraction
    return answer = x-y
end

function multiplication
    return answer = x*y
end

function division
    return answer = x/y
end
```

I've tried using

```
if op = 1 then
      answer = x+y
      print(answer)
if op = 2 then
      answer = x-y
      print(answer)
```

and I did that completing each operation. But it doesn't work. I can't even get the error code that it's returning because it closes so fast. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, make these changes: You `require` operations.lua without the extension. Include parameters in your `operations` function definitions. Return the operation expression directly versus returning a statement like `answer = x+y`.

All together:

Code for operations.lua

```
function addition(x,y)
    return x + y
end

--more functions go here...

function division(x,y)
    return x / y
end
```

Code for your hosting Lua script:

```
require "operations"

result = addition(5,7)
print(result)

result = division(9,3)
print(result)
```

Once you get that working, try re-adding your `io` logic.

Keep in mind that as it's coded, your functions will be defined globally. To avoid polluting the global table, consider defining operations.lua as a module. Take a look at the [lua-users.org Modules Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try working on it when I get home. It's hard to work without access to SciTE because I can't get the error to show for me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The right `if-then-else` syntax:

```
if op==1 then
   answer = a+b
elseif op==2 then
   answer = a*b
end
print(answer)
```

After: please check the correct function-declaration syntax.

After: `return answer=x+y` is incorrect. If you want set `answer`'s value, set without `return`. If you want return the sum, please use `return x+y`.

And I think you should check [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/).

Comment: Thank you, I've been having trouble with the if-then-else syntax. I'm still a beginner in Lua, I've only written two scripts other than this calculator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, learn to use the command line so you can see the errors (on Windows that would be `cmd.exe`).

Second, change the second line to `require("operations")`. The way you did it the interpreter expects a directory `operations` with an underlying script `lua.lua`.

Comment: I'd use the command line if it wasn't blocked. Right now I'm working from my school computer and cmd.exe is a blocked application. I had it originally as require "operations" but I changed it to operations.lua since operations wasn't working. I have SciTE at my house and that's what I was using to view errors yesterday when I worked on the main part of the script. I'll work on it at home and see if I can figure it out. Thank you for helping.